# Migrate Sharepoint 2007 and database from two separate servers to one physical server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, migrate, sql-server-2005-express

I'm looking for any advice on the best way to migrate a SharePoint 2007 installation and a database. The current setup is a server running SharePoint 2007 with the database stored on a separate SQL Server installation. Due to performance issues we are planning to move the SharePoint application to another server and also move the database onto the same physical server and run it using SQL Server 2005 Express.

Has anyone done this type of migration before and could they recommend the best way to carry this out or if it is even possible. Migrating the SharePoint installation from one physical server to another seems fairly straight forward using stsadm.exe. Can anyone advise the best way to move the database from an SQL Server to SQL Server Express so that the SharePoint installation will be able to see it?

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using Tzunami's tools and products for SharePoint migration. Their site provides various demo videos and other information regarding content migration. They give user-friendly instructions, making the process quick and easy!

Their products are listed on the site- check them out at http://www.tzunami.com/products/Product-Overview.

Hope this helps!